# CFile::Open no instance of overloaded function

Tags: c++, mfc, cfile

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
CFile cfile_object;
cfile_object.Open("c:\\test\\ucancode_cfile_example.txt", CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite);
}
```

Error: No instance of overloaded function CFile::open
Please help

Comment: Do you mean that this doesn't compile and this is the error you receive? Because your snippet of code seems legall

Comment: If this is a Unicode build, you'll need to use the `_T("")` macro around your pathname.